# 4x7 rectangle divided into 7 different rectangles

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

Can you divide a 4x7 rectangle into 7 rectangles all of different area? Can you find multiple solutions?

Good luck!

P.S. @Deusovi wanted me to make puzzles that have an "aha moment", so here is my attempt at that.

Comment: A better/ more optimal answer has been given. Please consider transferring the check to that answer, since it fits the solution better. Nevertheless, you have the final decision: this is only a reminder. Happy puzzling!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For completeness, I found all the solutions with integer-sided rectangles. As already noted, with 7 areas totalling 28 you are constrained to use areas 1 through 7, and only areas 4 and 6 have two possible sizes. So running that through my solver I get 272 solutions (excluding rotations/reflections).

The solutions:

> [image]

Comment: Thx Omega Krypton, I forgot how to do spoilers

Comment: Great work! Thank you for such a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first work out the sizes of the rectangles.

> The only way to partition $28$ into 7 different positive integer values is $1+2+3+4+5+6+7$.
>  The $4$ rectangle can be $1\times4$ or $2\times2$, and the $6$ can be $1\times6$ or $2\times3$. The others all have width $1$.

It turns out every combination of these shapes is possible.

> ```
>  7 7 7 7 7 7 7
>  6 6 6 6 6 6 1
>  5 5 5 5 5 2 2
>  4 4 4 4 3 3 3
>  
>  7 7 7 7 7 7 7
>  6 6 5 5 5 5 5
>  6 6 4 4 3 3 3
>  6 6 4 4 2 2 1
>  
>  7 7 7 7 7 7 7
>  6 6 5 5 5 5 5
>  6 6 4 4 4 4 1
>  6 6 3 3 3 2 2
>  
>  7 7 7 7 7 7 7
>  6 6 6 6 6 6 1
>  4 4 3 3 3 2 2
>  4 4 5 5 5 5 5
> ```
>
> Note that any sub-rectangle in these partitions can be rotated or flipped to get an alternative arrangement.

Comment: Very well done!